# Convert integer date format to human readable format

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, date

I have a date time format where dates are represented as integers from 1/1/1900 .
For example: 1 is 1/1/1900 and 42998 is 20/9/2017.

How can I convert this format to a human readable format like dd/mm/yyyy ? I checked [datetime](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html) documentation but I did not find any way to do this. I want to do this either on python 3 or 2.7.

Thanks for any suggestion.

Comment: Shouldn't the date be 21/9/2017?

Comment: I used excel convert this number to date and it returned me 20/9/2017

Comment: I don't know how excel is doing this but python disagrees for some reason I get different results depending on where I do the calculations: http://www.convertit.com/Go/ConvertIt/Calculators/Date_and_Time/Date_Time_Diff_Calc.ASP agrees with you and this https://www.epochconverter.com/date-difference agrees with python

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define your dates as offsets from your basetime and construct a datetime:

```
In[22]:
import datetime as dt
dt.datetime(1900,1,1) + dt.timedelta(42998)

Out[22]: datetime.datetime(2017, 9, 22, 0, 0)
```

Once it's a `datetime` object you can convert this to a `str` via `strftime` using whatever format you desire:

```
In[24]:
(dt.datetime(1900,1,1) + dt.timedelta(42998-1)).strftime('%d/%m/%Y')

Out[24]: '21/09/2017'
```

So you can define a user func to do this:

```
In[27]:
def dtToStr(val):
    base = dt.datetime(1900,1,1)
    return (base + dt.timedelta(val-1)).strftime('%d/%m/%Y')
dtToStr(42998)

Out[27]: '21/09/2017'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import datetime

base_date = datetime.datetime(1900, 1, 1)
convert = lambda x: base_date + datetime.timedelta(days=x-1)
>>> convert(42998)
datetime.datetime(2017, 9, 21, 0, 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `datetime` object to do that.

```
import datetime
d = datetime.datetime(1900, 1, 1, 0, 0)
d + datetime.timedelta(days = 42998)
>> datetime.datetime(2017, 9, 22, 0, 0)
```